# How to construct a 2-dimensional array in ATS?

Tags: ats

For instance, I am looking for an example in ATS that does more or less what the following C code does:

```
int *theMultable[10][10];

void
theMultable_initialize()
{
  int i, j;
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) theMultable[i][j] := i * j;
  }
  return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach is to attempt a direct translation to C. However, I now think that I should have used builtin `matrix` type instead. This code relies on quite a bit of advanced functionality (I even left one unproven lemma for exercise: it shows that `N*sizeof(T) == sizeof(@[T][N])`.

The loop to initialize a 2-dimensional array is implemented in the function:

```
extern
fun
multable_init (
  mat: &(@[@[int][10]][10])? >> _
): void // end of [multable_init]
```

This function, in turn, uses two functions (both initialize an array of elements, basically). Also, the global variable `multable` is allocated, and is then initialized using `multable_init` (I thought it wouldn't work, but it did!).

Here's the code of initialization of the global variable:

```
var multable : @[int?][100]
val p_multable = addr@multable
prval pf_multable = array_v_group (view@multable)
val () = multable_init (!p_multable)
prval pf_multable = array_v_ungroup (pf_multable)
prval pf_multable = array2matrix_v (pf_multable)
val theMultable = ref_make_viewptr {matrix (int, 10, 10)} (pf_multable | p_multable)
```

A mutable array is allocated on stack, then we take its address (line 2), turns its corresponding at-proof from `@[int?][100]` to `@[@[int?][10]][10]` (via grouping on line 3), and initialize it. Then, we turn the grouped-array view into a matrix view, and finally, put it into a ref-cell.

The full code is at [Glot.io](https://glot.io/snippets/ejypap9azw)

Comment: Any possible hints as to proving the remaining lemma? This seems like a good exercise in the ATS theorem proving capabilities but I fail to find a starting point.

Comment: think that practically speaking, it should be postulated because showing it would be extremely tedious, if possible. Also, the code is written this way (with grouped array views) because I adapted it from my earlier code for low-dimensional matrices, where it provides some code reuse with vectors (a column matrix is viewed as N rows of column-vectors); if we know how to initialize a column-vector, then it's easy to initialize a matrix consisting of these.